# How save and use navigation context of current part of Panorama Page?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

In my panorama Page I can find out what part of panorama is now watching by user:

```
  void DialogPanorama_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {

                FeedItemViewModel feedItem = null;
                if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    feedItem = e.AddedItems[0] as FeedItemViewModel;
                    if (feedItem != null) NavigationContext.QueryString["ITEM_ID"] = feedItem.FeedMessage.Guid;
                }

            }
```

I have tried to change  NavigationContext.QueryString["ITEM_ID"], but then I need to use this Uri in App.xaml.cs, How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to pass parameters around?
You can simple use the Panorama control's SelectedIndex Property to know which panoramaitem is being seen by the user at any given moment :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama.selectedindex(v=vs.92).aspx